# Get max and min value's unique id while using group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a table with columns: `unique_id, product, root_location, price` with more than 50 million records

I want the result to be `product, min_price, min_price_unique_id, max_price, max_price_unique_id`

My query:

```
select product
    , min(price) as min_price
    , max(price) as max_price
from mytable
group by product
```

How to get the unique id's of min and max price?

Comment: use [row_number()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `RANK` and `STRING_AGG` with conditional aggregation as the following:

```
SELECT  product,
        MIN(price) AS min_price,
        STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN unique_id END, ',') min_price_unique_id,
        MAX(price) AS max_price,
        STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN unique_id END, ',') max_price_unique_id
FROM
(
  SELECT *,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY price) rn1,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY price DESC) rn2
  FROM tbl_name
) T
WHERE rn1 =1 OR rn2 =1
GROUP BY product
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/fv0b1op0)

Update:
To get the unique `donator_ids` values in case duplicates have existed,  you could use another subquery/ CTE, and use the row_number function partitioned by product, unique_id then get only rows where row_number =1.

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
  SELECT *,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY price) rn1,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY price DESC) rn2
  FROM tbl_name
),
CTE2 AS
(
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product, unique_id ORDER BY unique_id) row_num
  FROM CTE1
)
SELECT  product,
        MIN(price) AS min_price,
        STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN unique_id END, ',') min_price_unique_id,
        MAX(price) AS max_price,
        STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN unique_id END, ',') max_price_unique_id
FROM CTE2
WHERE (rn1 =1 OR rn2 =1) AND  row_num =1
GROUP BY product
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/BaP2UzRm)

Comment: You should give them a try to decide which one is better for you, but usually, window functions perform better than joins.

Comment: I think adding an index on (product, price) would be helpful here, maybe

Comment: I have one doubt, in my case there are some duplicate rows, in that case the `string_agg` will produce same id multiple times, is there a way to aggregate only distinct id's without using distinct keyword?

Comment: Well, without using distinct, I think you could use another subquery/ CTE, and use the row_number function partitioned by product, price, and ordered by `unique_id` then get only rows where  row_number =1.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/BaP2UzRm `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product, unique_id ORDER BY unique_id)`

Comment: Can you update your answer by adding this changes?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select a.*, b.unique_id as min_price_unique_id, c.unique_id as max_price_unique_id
from (
  select product
    , min(price) as min_price
    , max(price) as max_price
  from mytable
  group by product
) a
join mytable b
  on a.min_price = b.price
join mytable c
  on a.max_price = c.price
```

This query uses two joins to the original table `mytable` to get the unique ids of the minimum and maximum prices. 1.  The subquery calculates the max and min price for each product and the subquery  `a`  is joined with the original table  `mytable`  twice. Once to get the unique id of the minimum price and then to get the unique id of the maximum price. The join condition for both joins is the price column.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_2Kf1RO8)

Comment: This was really helpful. There could be a possibility to have multiple unique id's for same `min_price` and same for `max_price`. What will be the right way to represent this?  Your query will add new rows for each unique id, is it possible to get all unique id's in one cell with comma separation?

Comment: When I apply the same query to my data, I was getting more than 16k rows, where It need to be only 9 rows. The difference is that, in my case `mytable` is a `cte` with multiple joins and other difference is instead of only product, I have 4 columns to group by. Your query is working till sub query as expected(getting 9 rows with min and max price), when I add those self joins, it's giving 16k+ rows.

Comment: You can try [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/PAKdkqBU) when you have multiple unique ids for min_price or max_price.

Comment: In simple terms, your query is not working when there is same min price for different products, can you update that?

Comment: Did you check this [code](https://dbfiddle.uk/1madxzIy)?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want with the `unique_id`. In the situation where there are multiple `unique_id` for the `min` or `max` price, do you want to return all `unique_id` or just only one.

Depending on your requirement, use `row_number()` or `dense_rank()`. Do check out the documentation for the details on these 2 window functions.

Below query will return One `unique_id` per `product`.

```
select product,
       min_price           = max(case when min_rn = 1 then price end),
       min_price_unique_id = max(case when min_rn = 1 then unique_id end),
       max_price           = max(case when max_rn = 1 then price end),
       max_price_unique_id = max(case when max_rn = 1 then unique_id end)
from
(
    select *, 
           min_rn = row_number() over (partition by product order by price),
           max_rn = row_number() over (partition by product order by price desc)
    from   mytable
) t
group by product
```

---

Edit : if you do want to show all the corresponding `unique_id` for the min and max price, here is one way. Use 2 separate query to identify the min and max price after that join using `full outer join` (as there might be different number of `unique_id` rows in the min or max price)

```
with 
min_price as
(
    select  product, min_price = price, unique_id, 
            rn = row_number() over (partition by product order by unique_id)
    from
    (
        select *, 
               min_rn = dense_rank() over (partition by product order by price)
        from   mytable
    ) m
    where min_rn = 1
),
max_price as
(
    select  product, max_price = price, unique_id, 
            rn = row_number() over (partition by product order by unique_id)
    from
    (
        select *, 
               max_rn = dense_rank() over (partition by product order by price desc)
        from   mytable
    ) m
    where max_rn = 1
) 
select mn.product, mn.min_price, mn.unique_id, mx.max_price, mx.unique_id
from   min_price mn
       full outer join max_price mx on  mn.product = mx.product
                                    and mn.rn      = mx.rn
order by mn.product, mn.unique_id, mx.unique_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is on thing that I am confused with, there is a chance that unique id will be same for some products. Is it possible to select the id from the row where there is max or min is selected and if there are multiple id's for min or max, return them all (distinct of all id's)? I am worrying about the performance in this approach. I need to use `dense_rank` if I want to return all the `id's`, right? but how to get only distinct of id's without distinct keyword? (as distinct reduce the performance?)

Comment: if you want to return all the `unique_id` how do you want the result to looks like ? Note that changing to use `dense_rank()` in the above query does not return all `unique_id` , that is only first step for identifying the `unique_id` that correspond to the min or max price

Comment: I am fine with both like either new_row for each id or concatenate all the id's with comma separation in a single row, which ever will have a good performance.